# Making a pause screen

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to make a pause screen function but the images shutter and appear with a good delay. Any
ideas Heres my code:

```
PauseLogo = pg.image.load('Stop.png')
Pause = pg.image.load('Pause.png')

#------------------------------------------
while running:
clock.tick(FPS)
for event in pg.event.get():
    if event.type == pg.QUIT:
        running = False
    if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
        
        if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
            paused = not paused


    if paused == True:
        clock.tick(27)
        screen.blit(PauseLogo, (0,0))
        screen.blit(Pause, (400, 330))
        

   


if not paused:
    all_sprites.update()

screen.fill(DARKGRAY)
all_sprites.draw(screen)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: When i try to fix it code is outside of the thingy but the problem isnt in the indentation of the original code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw different scenes dependent on the state of `paused`:

```py
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
    
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                paused = not paused

    if paused == True:
        screen.blit(PauseLogo, (0,0))
        screen.blit(Pause, (400, 330))
    else:
        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill(DARKGRAY)
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Note, [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) measures the time since the last call of this function and delays the application. If you call it twice in the application, the application is delayed twice.